# WPF Animation: Complete callback not called if to == from

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I'd like to find a cleaner way to get the animation complete callback to fire when to == from. Right now I hack this to work by adding a small amount to my from value. Is there a better way?

```
    //todo is there a way to get animations to call their Complete() even when to == from?
    if (to.Equals(from)) {
        from += .01;
    }

    DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation {
        Name = axis == Axis.X ? TranslateTransform.XProperty.Name : TranslateTransform.YProperty.Name,
        From = from,
        To = to,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(translate.Time),
        FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop,
        EasingFunction = translate.Curve.ToEase(),
        IsAdditive = false,

    };

    AnimationClock = animation.CreateClock();

    AnimationClock.Completed += (sender, args) => {

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check values before the creation of the animation.
 If the Duration is important you can start a timer and launch the code when it ticks.

Something like this should do the trick :

```
if (to.Equals(from)) {
        if (_timer == null)
        {
            _timer = new Timer(x =>
            {
                //completeCode
            }, null, translate.Time * 1000, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
        else
        {
            _timer.Change(translate.Time * 1000, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
    return;       
}
```

Comment: It's resource costly to create Timer every time best it to store it in a class variable.